# Event handler for SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Below is code for handling events in SFML. It works by reading a text file containing a sequence of functions to be called when a given event is detected:

**EventManager.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace AGE
{
    enum class EventType
    {
        KeyDown       = sf::Event::KeyPressed,
        KeyUp         = sf::Event::KeyReleased,
        MButtonDown   = sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed,
        MButtonUp     = sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased,
        MouseWheel    = sf::Event::MouseWheelMoved,
        WindowResized = sf::Event::Resized,
        GainedFocus   = sf::Event::GainedFocus,
        LostFocus     = sf::Event::LostFocus,
        MouseEntered  = sf::Event::MouseEntered,
        MouseLeft     = sf::Event::MouseLeft,
        Closed        = sf::Event::Closed,
        TextEntered   = sf::Event::TextEntered,
        Keyboard      = sf::Event::Count + 1, Mouse, Joystick
    };



    struct EventInfo
    {
        EventInfo()
        {
            this->code = 0;
        }

        EventInfo(int code)
        {
            this->code = code;
        }

        int code;
    };

    using Events = std::vector<std::pair<EventType, EventInfo>>;

    struct EventDetails
    {
        EventDetails(const std::string& binding_name)
        {
            this->binding_name = binding_name;
            Clear();
        }

        void Clear()
        {
            this->size              = { 0, 0 };
            this->text_entered      = { 0 };
            this->mouse             = { 0, 0 };
            this->mouse_wheel_delta = { 0 };
            this->key_code          = { -1 };
        }

        std::string binding_name;

        sf::Vector2i size;
        sf::Uint32 text_entered;
        sf::Vector2i mouse;
        int mouse_wheel_delta;
        int key_code;
    };



    struct Binding
    {
        Binding(const std::string& name) :
        details(name),
        name(name),
        event_count(0)
        {}

        void BindEvent(EventType type, EventInfo info = EventInfo())
        {
            this->events.emplace_back(type, info);
        }

        EventDetails details;
        Events       events;
        std::string  name;
        int          event_count;
    };

    using Bindings = std::unordered_map<std::string, Binding*>;
    using Callbacks = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(EventDetails*)>>;

    class EventManager
    {
    public:
         EventManager();
        ~EventManager();

        bool AddBinding(Binding* binding);
        bool RemoveBinding(const std::string& name);

        void HandleEvent(sf::Event& event);
        void Update();

        void SetFocus(const bool focus);

        template <class T>
        bool AddCallback(const std::string& name,
                         void(T::*function)(EventDetails*), 
                         T* class_instance)
        {
            auto func = std::bind(function, class_instance, std::placeholders::_1);
            return this->callbacks.emplace(name, func).second;
        }

        void RemoveCallback(const std::string& name)
        {
            this->callbacks.erase(name);
        }


    private:
        void LoadBindings();

    private:
        Callbacks callbacks;
        Bindings  bindings;
        bool has_focus;
    };
}
```

**EventManager.cpp**

```
#include "EventManager.hpp"

namespace AGE
{
    EventManager::EventManager() :
    has_focus(true)
    {
        LoadBindings();
    }



    EventManager::~EventManager()
    {
        for (auto& itr : this->bindings)
        {
            delete itr.second;
            itr.second = nullptr;
        }
    }



    bool EventManager::AddBinding(Binding* binding)
    {
        if (this->bindings.find(binding->name) != this->bindings.end())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this->bindings.emplace(binding->name, binding).second;
    }



    bool EventManager::RemoveBinding(const std::string& name)
    {
        auto itr = this->bindings.find(name);
        if (itr != this->bindings.end())
        {
            delete itr->second;
            this->bindings.erase(itr);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }



    void EventManager::HandleEvent(sf::Event& event)
    {
        for (auto& b_itr : this->bindings)
        {
            Binding* binding = b_itr.second;

            for (auto& e_itr : binding->events)
            {
                EventType event_type = static_cast<EventType>(event.type);

                if (e_itr.first != event_type) { continue; };

                if ((event_type == EventType::KeyDown) || (event_type == EventType::KeyUp))
                {
                    if (e_itr.second.code == event.key.code)
                    {
                        ++(binding->event_count);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if ((event_type == EventType::MButtonDown) || (event_type == EventType::MButtonUp))
                {
                    if (e_itr.second.code == event.mouseButton.button)
                    {
                        binding->details.mouse.x = event.mouseButton.x;
                        binding->details.mouse.y = event.mouseButton.y;
                        ++(binding->event_count);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (event_type == EventType::MouseWheel)
                    {
                        binding->details.mouse_wheel_delta = event.mouseWheel.delta;
                    }
                    else if (event_type == EventType::WindowResized)
                    {
                        binding->details.size.x = event.size.width;
                        binding->details.size.y = event.size.height;
                    }
                    else if (event_type == EventType::TextEntered)
                    {
                        binding->details.text_entered = event.text.unicode;
                    }
                    ++(binding->event_count);
                }
            }
        }
    }



    void EventManager::Update()
    {
        if (!this->has_focus) { return; };

        for (auto& b_itr : this->bindings)
        {
            Binding* binding = b_itr.second;

            for (auto& e_itr : binding->events)
            {
                switch (e_itr.first)
                {
                default:
                    break;

                case EventType::Keyboard:
                    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key(e_itr.second.code)))
                    {
                        ++(binding->event_count);
                    }
                    break;

                case EventType::Mouse:
                    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button(e_itr.second.code)))
                    {
                        ++(binding->event_count);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                if (binding->events.size() == binding->event_count)
                {
                    auto callback_itr = this->callbacks.find(binding->name);
                    if (callback_itr != this->callbacks.end())
                    {
                        callback_itr->second(&binding->details);
                    }
                }
                binding->event_count = 0;
                binding->details.Clear();
            }
        }
    }



    void EventManager::SetFocus(const bool focus)
    {
        this->has_focus = focus;
    }



    void EventManager::LoadBindings()
    {
        const std::string deliminator = ":";
        std::ifstream     bindings;
        bindings.open("C:/dev/MyVSProjects/C++/Racer/Racer/Racer/src/Keys.cfg");

        if (!bindings.is_open())
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open key file!" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(bindings, line))
        {
            std::stringstream key_stream(line);
            std::string callback_name;
            key_stream >> callback_name;
            Binding* binding = new Binding(callback_name);

            while (!key_stream.eof())
            {
                std::string key_value;
                key_stream >> key_value;

                int start = 0;
                int end = key_value.find(deliminator);
                if (end == std::string::npos)
                {
                    delete binding;
                    binding = nullptr;
                    break;
                }
                EventType type = EventType(std::stoi(key_value.substr(start, end - start)));
                int code = std::stoi(key_value.substr(end + deliminator.length(), key_value.find(deliminator, end + deliminator.length())));
                EventInfo event_info;
                event_info.code = code;
                binding->BindEvent(type, event_info);
            }

            if (!AddBinding(binding)) { delete binding; };
        }

        bindings.close();
    }
}
```

Short example: (Keys.cfg then tells the code to call function "cout" when keybutton 89 (f5) is pressed)

**Keys.cfg**

```
COUT 5:89
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "EventManager.hpp"

#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() = default;

    void COUT(AGE::EventDetails* details)
    {
        std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Test");
    AGE::EventManager event_manager;
    event_manager.AddCallback("COUT", &Test::COUT, &test);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::LostFocus)
            {
                event_manager.SetFocus(false);
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::GainedFocus)
            {
                event_manager.SetFocus(true);
            }
            event_manager.HandleEvent(event);
        }
        event_manager.Update();

        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }
}
```

I would like any tips to improve the code in any way possible. Looking to learn!

Answer (score 1):

Data modeling wise:

- The name `EventInfo` is ambiguous, especially when there is another class called `EventDetails`. So I am thinking about how to make their purposes more differentiable. It seems like the purpose of `EventInfo` and `EventType` is to create a composite key, which is used in `EventManager` to fork business logic.  I would recommend creating a structure `EventClassifier` which has both event type and event code as member variables. `Binding` can have an unordered set of `EventClassifier`.

Coding style-wise:

- prefer to use initialization list rather than assignment operator in the constructor. For instance:

```
EventInfo(int a_code)
:  code(a_code)
{}
```

- It is redundant to write `this->size` in function `void Clear()`. It can just be `size`.
- you can use structured bindings when iterating thru a map: `for (const auto& [k,v] : bindg->events)`. the code will be more readable as you don't need to write things like `iter->second`.

Some other things:

- in `EventManager` destructor, the code should check `if(itr.second)` before freeing the memory.
- `EventManager::AddBinding` takes a raw pointer of `Binding`. This is unsafe because 1) EventManager will free the memory in `RemoveBinding`. so it assumed the address is on heap however there is no guarantee. 2) Caller of `EventManager::AddBinding` has access to the binding object and could have freed the memory. Then when EventManager tries to access it, the program will segfault.  I would recommend changing the interface of `AddBinding(Binding* binding)` to `AddBinding(const std::string& callback_name, EventType type, int event_code)`. Then EventManager has the ownership of `binding` objects exclusively.